# How Can I pass a Data list to CreateAsync Func?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with `CreateAsync`, it wants IOrderedQueryable.
I need to read just two records `(Id,Title)` from my News table and pass them to my `ViewModel` but it doesn't let me pass `RetValue (list type)` in `CreateAsync`.

```
var MyNews = _context.News.Select(news => new
{
    news.Id,
    news.Title,
}).AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(p => p.Id);
List<ListNewsViewModel> RetValue = new List<ListNewsViewModel>();
foreach (var item in MyNews)
{
    ListNewsViewModelLN = new ListNewsViewModel();
    LN.Id = item.Id;
    LN.Title = item.Title;
    RetValue.Add(LN);
}
var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(RetValue, 10, PageIndex);
model.Action = "EditNews";
return View(model);
```

Comment: - What's the error message you are getting from the compiler?

- Is `PagingList` a class of your own, or from a library?

Comment: Please tell me what type to expect the CreateAsync method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do like this:

```
var MyNews = (from q in _context.News
               select new ListNewsViewModel()
               {
                    Id = q.Id;
                    Title = q.Title;
               })
               .AsNoTracking()
               .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id);
var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(MyNews, 10, PageIndex);
model.Action = "EditNews";
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `List<T>` Which is not IQueryable But IEnumerable.

Pass the query result directly:

```
var MyNews = _context.News.Select(news => new ListNews
{
    Id = news.Id,
    Title  = news.Title,
}).AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(p => p.Id);

var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(MyNews, 10, PageIndex);
model.Action = "EditNews";
return View(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I set on my cshtml side to get data from ListNewsViewModel and I don't want to pass my News table data to cshtml because my News table has many records.  meanwhile I get error when I just select two records(Id,Title) and it needs to select all records

Comment: @MoeinKhakpour, what does it mean "I don't want to pass my News table data "? You are loading whole table into the memory - worst scenario. Try this variant, it should work as expected.

Comment: I dont want to load my whole data, that's why I define a ViewModel but my problem is that I cant pass RetValue on CreateAsync, because it accepts IOrderedQueryable and the RetValue is List type. Morover when I wrote your code I got this error: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList`1[AtlasNews.Models.News]'.